# R's C API, Creating a Dataframe

Tags: r, c

I have a dataframe in R which I want to re-create in C:

```r
 col1 col2
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
```

How would I go about re-creating this in C?
So far I have:

```c
      SEXP vec = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 2)), // vector size, allocates the amount of columns            
            nms = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 2)), // names, for the column names above the dataframe                 
            rnms = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 3)); //row names                 
   
       for(size_t r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
           for(size_t c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
               SEXP _col;                             
               Rf_protect(_col = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
               REAL(_col)[0] = c;                            
  
               SET_VECTOR_ELT(vec, c, _col);
          }                                
      }
```

Yet I am completely stuck in how to add columns to a vector.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069149/creating-a-r-data-frame-in-c-c

Comment: @MrFlick it did somewhat, although I still don't know how to add multiple rows...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The sample answer there adds 10 rows to the data.frame. I'm not sure how your code is different.